# Mysql Event Not Working

Tags: mysql, mysql-event, mysql-routines

I have added the following simple test event on my mysql database via phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `my_event` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2013-05-27 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
BEGIN
    UPDATE `test` SET `name`="z";
END
```

My environment is mac + MAMP Pro. I am expecting to change all rows on my 'test' table with name 'z' within a minute. But not happening so.

Do I have to something additional to get my events start working?

Output of "SHOW PROCESSLIST":
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the results of the query `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` ? Maybe the scheduler is not started.

Comment: just added the output to my question description. I didn't do anything to start the scheduler. How to start it please?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Events are run by the scheduler, which is not started by default.
Using `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is possible to check whether it is started. If not, run the command

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

to run it.

Comment: Be careful: it's possible that `SHOW PROCESSLIST` won't show the running process even if it is in fact running - that happens in my Plesk based web hosting in an account where I don't have root privileges. The event_scheduler is running, but it doesn't appear in the list. For me it's better to use `select @@event_scheduler`; it will return `ON`in case it is.

Comment: @Jac_opo i have follow your instruction but nothing happen, i have set global to be on and restart my server but nothing happen, by the if my event about one month how can i tested ? i tested by change date but nothing happend,

Comment: @Rana how can i debug it ? i use phpmyadmin but doesn't work, please goes to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400140/auto-add-field-each-user-using-event-nothing-error-and-doesnt-working

Answer (score 14):

Verify if the event_scheduler is On - execute the following command:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

It'll output a table/entries, you must look for an entry with **User** `event_scheduler`, and **Command** `Daemon`:

```
Id           User         Host      db  Command Time    State            Info
22870   event_scheduler localhost   \N   Daemon  23    Waiting for next activation  \N
```

OR, you can also verify using the following command:

```
SELECT @@global.event_scheduler;
```

The result should be `ON`, otherwise set it off (will get `0` for the command), as stated in the next section.

---

If you don't have any such entry (as above), you may start the event scheduler using the following command:

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Once done, you can verify if it has been executed properly using the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 13):

For those wondering how to enable it by default at startup, add the following to your config file (my.ini, my.cnf):

```
#Event scheduler can be set to 1 (On), 0 (Off), or Disabled
event_scheduler=1
```

Restart of the service is required in this case, so if you want minimal disruption, add this to the config file, and then run the SQL:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

That way, it will run for the current process, and if the server is restarted it will still work.

Note that this doesn't work if the event_scheduler was set to disabled. In that case the only option is to restart the service.

Comment: I would like to add that `event_scheduler=1` goes under the `[mysqld]` section of the config file.

Comment: It's very important to add the event_scheduler=1 (or =ON) line to the correct configuration file.  I added it to my.cnf, restarted MySQL service and it worked for a while and then after 24 hours I couldn't start MySQL service until I removed it.  It turns out that if my.cnf has references to mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf that it is best to add the line into that configuration file and it works properly from there.

Answer (score 12):

If you want your `event_scheduler` to startup automatically every time mysql server restarts, anywhere under the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.ini` or `my.cnf` file that you find in `/etc/mysql` you should place

```
[mysqld]

# turning on event_scheduler  
event_scheduler=ON
```

restart mysql to check if it is running (in command line terminal!)

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

then check your processlist

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

you can check if your events are running by checking the last time they ran

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.events
```

Comment: Though @Jacopofar's answer helps, your answer provides complete solution for me. Thank you, Up voting your answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

### Temporal

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

*Will not work if event_scheduler is explicitly **DISABLED**, see the method below*

### Permanent (needs restart)

In your config file (In Ubuntu it's `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`):

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = ON
```

#### Notes:

The `event_scheduler` variable can have this possible states:

- **OFF** (or **0**) (default)
- **ON** (or **1**)
- **DISABLED**: you cannot use the **temporal enabling**, you can only change state through the config file and restarting the server

**WARNING:** Keywords **ON / OFF** are preferred over their numerical equivalents.
And in fact **Mysql Workbench** doesn't recognize the configuration `event_scheduler=1`, it shows as **OFF** in the **Options File** section.
*Tested in Ubuntu with Mysql Workbench 8.0.17 and Mysql Server 5.7.27*

> Although **ON** and **OFF** have numeric equivalents, the value
>   displayed for event_scheduler by SELECT or SHOW VARIABLES is always
>   one of **OFF**, **ON**, or **DISABLED**. **DISABLED** has no numeric
>   equivalent. For this reason, **ON** and **OFF** are usually preferred
>   over **1** and **0** when setting this variable.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that on MariaDB, after adding an event (in my case, it was the first one), you have to restart the event-scheduler

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
```

and then

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

to make it actually bring the scheduler into "waiting for activation"-state.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add to this thread. I dumped my database to another server and as a result the definer of my event had no such grant defined for the user. I updated my definer with

```
ALTER DEFINER='root'@'localhost' EVENT event.name COMMENT '';
```

Make sure your definer has the correct PRIVILEGES.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add in '**Commit**', after '**DO BEGIN**' or '**DO**'. Works for me after that.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`db01` EVENT `PRICEALERT_STATUS` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) 
DO BEGIN
// Your Query
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This won't work because the event has to run first for that event_scheduler to be turned on.