# Mariadb large deletion with join and limit

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-delete

I'm trying to remove a lot of rows

My query is pretty simple but there is a `JOIN` and `LIMIT` is not allowed with that. I don't really understand why since it's not a `LEFT JOIN`.

I would like to wrap it in an event scheduler within a batch. I'm currently stuck with the `LIMIT` part.

```sql
# working
DELETE invitations from invitations JOIN events on events.id = invitations.event_id WHERE (...)

# not working
DELETE invitations from invitations JOIN events on events.id = invitations.event_id WHERE (...) LIMIT 10
```

I had something like that in mind

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE EVENT invitation_cleaner_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2023-05-26 04:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
    REPEAT
        DO SLEEP(1);  
        # my query to delete with join and limit
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
END
```

Comment: It generally does not make sense to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  What is the determining _which_ 10 records should be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, deeply inspired by Michal's (thanks again).
I still have a down time issue (duration depends on the number of records to remove) so it might be upgraded with knowledge I don't have.

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE EVENT invitation_cleaner_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2023-05-27 02:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
    DECLARE rows_deleted INT;
    SET rows_deleted = 1;
    WHILE rows_deleted > 0 DO
      DELETE invitations
      FROM invitations
      JOIN (
        SELECT invitations.id
        FROM invitations
        JOIN events ON events.id=invitations.event_id WHERE ...
        LIMIT 1000
      ) AS subquery ON subquery.id = invitations.id;

      SET rows_deleted = ROW_COUNT();
      DO SLEEP(1);
    END WHILE;
END
show events;
```

**EDIT**

Very important to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57662121) where I actually learnt how to enable scheduler **permanently**  (requires a restart of the db)

```
# /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = ON
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, the `LIMIT` clause is not allowed in a `DELETE` statement that includes a `JOIN`. This limitation exists because the `LIMIT` clause applies to the overall result set, not to individual tables involved in the `JOIN`. Therefore, it can potentially lead to ambiguous or unintended behavior.

Instead of using `LIMIT` directly in the `DELETE` statement, you can use a subquery with the `LIMIT` clause to retrieve the specific rows to delete, and then use that result in the `JOIN` condition:

```
DELETE invitations
FROM invitations
JOIN (
  SELECT events.id
  FROM invitations
  JOIN events ON events.id = invitations.event_id
  LIMIT 10
) AS subquery ON subquery.id = invitations.event_id;
```

So your event scheduler would look like this:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE EVENT invitation_cleaner_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2023-05-26 04:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
  DECLARE rows_deleted INT;
  SET rows_deleted = 1;
  WHILE rows_deleted > 0 DO
    DELETE invitations
    FROM invitations
    JOIN (
      SELECT events.id
      FROM invitations
      JOIN events ON events.id = invitations.event_id
      LIMIT 10
    ) AS subquery ON subquery.id = invitations.event_id;

    SET rows_deleted = ROW_COUNT();
    DO SLEEP(1);
  END WHILE;
END
```

Also another approach is to use `IN` statement instead of `JOIN`. This might help overall performance of a query - I can't certainly say which one is faster until you try it on your data. But it is worth to give it a try.

```
CREATE EVENT invitation_cleaner_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2023-05-27 02:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
    DECLARE rows_deleted INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE batch_size INT DEFAULT 1000;
    
    WHILE rows_deleted > 0 DO
        DELETE FROM invitations
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT invitations.id
            FROM invitations
            JOIN events ON events.id = invitations.event_id
            WHERE ...
            LIMIT batch_size
        );

        SET rows_deleted = ROW_COUNT();
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: This looks nice! Thanks a lot!
I'll update the original query if you don't mind because I'm a bit lost with my own `a` and `b`.  
If you can update your answer with it, it would be awesome... ☺️

Comment: @brcebn I updated the query with the real names of your tables. Hoping it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were very close to the solution! I'll add mine. If you have a solution to avoid down time during this, I would love to hear it. ❤️

Comment: What do you mean by "down time"? It's deleting rows in a batch and loops until there's something left to be deleted. Another approach might be to perform a select which finds rows "to be deleted" and then you delete specifying ids in a `WHERE` condition. So if lock during delete is a problem which causes you downtime this will shorten this time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant requests are very slow and might now arrived at all (most of the time). SQL queries are performed fast enough but we are talking about millions of lines to remove every day. Currently it takes approx 30min for the event to be fully executed. During those 30min, app is not going well. 

Comment: I understand. I do not know how does the `WHERE` condition look like. But you can consider index usage on `WHERE` condition. Mind the "gap lock" - "gap" between two values in the index will be locked. So if you're probably not searching according to some index it might occur. Also try to play with amount of rows being deleted in one batch. Try to lower it - it might take longer, but application could be more responsive. Also do you perform it within a transaction? If yes, then I would recommend to avoid it, because transaction might keep it locked until job finishes and that causes slowness.

Comment: I also updated answer with another approach using `in` instead of `join`. Give it a try to see whether it's faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I cannot update the code from `JOIN` to `IN`. MariaDB does not support (10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1) it but I have lowered the batch_size to 500. 
I don't think I'm using a transaction here. Unless MySQL is doing it on its own during the event?

Comment: Ok, let's see what it does. MySQL should not add transaction by default. Also one thing came to my mind. Use `LOW_PRIORITY` on `DELETE` statement. This gives `select` a chance to obtain lock on rows being deleted. It may lead to better responsivity during delete operation. Disadvantage is that delete may take much longer.

Comment: 30min down this night with 500 as batch size.  
Actually, I'm not even sure there is a solution with the current one. Do you think it's possible to run a procedure only once and inside it, it's calling himself at the end if `rows_deleted > 0`? 
It's like a async job scheduler.

Comment: Have you also tried it with `LOW_PRIORITY`? When do you consider a row as "deletable"? Are you cleaning some old invitations? If so, you can also try table partitioning ... partition it by an invitation date and then just delete the partitions which contain old invitations. Also another approach might be to delete them more often (batch will not be such big).

Comment: I never thought about partitioning it. It's a good idea. It based on event date + invitation status. So I would make a partition based on invitation status and then join it with events and delete the partition. Would it work that way?
I have not tried "LOW_PRIORITY" yet.

Comment: I would try `LOW_PRIORITY` first as it is easier to try :) Partitioning would require some refactoring. I think you need to introduce a column saying how old the event is (in days) and partition by this. First partition contains only new events and the other contains old ones. Than you can just truncate the partition with old events which should be faster.

Comment: Such a good idea, thanks!
I've made the update for `LOW_PRIORITY` let's see tomorrow. 

Comment: 15min down, it's half the time it was before `LOW_PRIORITY`. I'll keep it like that. I just need to keep this app alive for a couple of months.  
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You're welcomme. Glad to hear it helped.